# User.IsInRole error

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization

I have this code inside the `Page_Load` of the `Site.Master.cs`.

```
if(User.IsInRole("Read"))
{
   NavigationMenu.Visible = false;
}
```

and I get this error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.User.IsInRole(string).

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the class instead an instance of that class try:

```
User user = new User();
user.IsInRole("Read");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get current [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) [user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) and validate for given role using [IsInRole method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.isinrole.aspx) as below.

`HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Read")`

Change your method as

```
if(HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Read"))
{
   NavigationMenu.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully agree with the answer. You are getting the `User` instance from the `Page` property in your master page, so you should use:

```
var user = Page.User;
user.IsInRole("your role");
```